# List comprehension works but not for loop––why?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, indexing, list-comprehension

I'm a bit annoyed with myself because I can't understand why one solution to a problem worked but another didn't. As in, it points to a deficient understanding of (basic) pandas on my part, and that makes me mad!

Anyway, my problem was simple: I had a list of 'bad' values ('bad_index'); these corresponded to row indexes on a dataframe ('data_clean1') for which I wanted to delete the corresponding rows. However, as the values will change with each new dataset, I didn't want to plug the bad values directly into the code. Here's what I did first:

```
bad_index = [2, 7, 8, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 24, 29]

for i in bad_index:
    dataclean2 = dataclean1.drop([i]).reset_index(level = 0, drop = True)
```

But this didn't work; the data_clean2 remained the exact same as data_clean1. My second idea was to use list comprehensions (as below); this worked out fine.

```
bad_index = [2, 7, 8, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 24, 29]

data_clean2 = data_clean1.drop([x for x in bad_index]).reset_index(level = 0, drop = True)
```

Now, why did the list comprehension method work and not the 'for' loop? I've been coding for a few months, and I feel that I shouldn't be making these kinds of errors.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what `drop` does but I know that in the `for loop` you are reassigning `dataclean2` during each iteration.

Comment: Do you mean list comprehension rather than regular expression? In terms if making errors, I've been coding for years and still run into issues that I don't understand, and make mistakes I feel I shouldn't! I wish I could tell you that mistakes disappear over time...

Comment: Yes, edited for clarity!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`data_clean1.drop([x for x in bad_index]).reset_index(level = 0, drop = True)` is equivalent to simply passing the `bad_index` list to `drop`:

`data_clean1.drop(bad_index).reset_index(level = 0, drop = True)`

`drop` accepts a list, and drops every index present in the list.

Your explicit `for` loop didn't work because in every iteration you simply dropped a different index from the `dataclean1` dataframe without saving the intermediate dataframes, so by the last iteration `dataclean2` was simply the result of executing
`dataclean2 = dataclean1.drop(29).reset_index(level = 0, drop = True)`

Comment: oh man thats what i get for not reading the question entirely +1 good answer

Comment: Great answer—thanks! This clarifies it very nicely. Funny thing is, I'd never have made this mistake iterating over a list. But at least I won't be making it again ...

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: it turns out this is not your problem ... but if you did not have the problem mentioned in the other answer by Deepspace then you would have this problem**

```
for i in bad_index:
    dataclean2 = dataclean1.drop([i]).reset_index(level = 0, drop = True)
```

imagine your bad index is `[1,2,3]` and your dataclean is `[4,5,6,7,8]`

**now lets step through what actually happens**

initial: `dataclean == [4,5,6,7,8]`

loop0 : i == 1 => drop index 1 ==>dataclean = `[4,6,7,8]`

loop1 : i == 2 => drop index 2 ==> dataclean = `[4,6,8]`

loop2 : i ==3 ==> drop index 3 !!!! uh oh there is no index 3

---

you could i guess do instead

```
for i in reversed(bad_index):
    ...
```

this way if you remove index3 first it will not affect index 1 and 2

**but in general you should not mutate a list/dict as you iterate over it**